# I am trying to make a password checker to see whether the password is between 8 - 20 characters, & has an uppercase, but cant seem to figure it out

Tags: c++

This is the code - the programme runs fine but when creating a user, if the password is still 2 characters long for example, it still shows as successful registration. Not exactly sure where to go from here (new to coding and its my first project solo, looking for guidance.) (sorry if its a clusterbomb of code its abit all over the place)

```cpp
void registration() {

    system("cls");
    bool valid = false;
    int minLength = 8;
    int maxLength = 20;

    string regUsername, regPassword, regUser, regPass;

    std::cout << "Welcome to the registration page!" << '\n';
    std::cout << "Please enter a username: " << '\n';
    std::cin >> regUsername;
    std::cout << "Enter a password that is 8-20 characters long, with an uppercase and lowercase \n";
    std::cin >> regPassword;


    if (regPassword.length() >= 8 || regPassword.length() <= 20) {

        for (int k = 0; k < regPassword.length(); k++)
        {
            if (isupper(regPassword[k]))
            {
                valid = true;

            }

        }
    }

    if (valid = true) {
        std::ofstream registerUser("records.txt", std::ios::app); // open records.txt to write username and password inside.
        registerUser << regUsername << " " << regPassword << std::endl;


        system("cls");
        int choice;
        std::cout << "Welcome aboard " << regUsername << ", your registration has been successful!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 1 if you would like to login, and 2 if you would like to return to the main menu." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: login();
            break;
        case 2: main();
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid input, returning to main menu." << std::endl;
            main();
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (valid = false) {
        std::cout << "Invalid password, please attempt to create an account again." << '\n';
        registration();
    }
}
```

I expected the password to be validated and checked for 8-20 characters along with if there is an uppercase within the password. i have tried changing the && to || but i dont think thats where the problem is.

Comment: `case 2: main();` -- Do not call `main`.  Write a regular old `for` or `while` loop.  All I have to do is write an input script that has bad input 10000 times, and bingo, a stack overflow error.  And in any event, it is not legal to call `main()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo They changed something else and the edit probably conflicted with yours.

Comment: `if (valid = true) {` <= this assigns `true` to `valid`. The `if` condition will therefore always be `true`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I guess they really want truthfulness

Comment: What @PaulMcKenzie mentions is really important. You are not even _allowed_ to call `main` in C++ (unlike in C). The program has undefined behavior as a result and it's pointless to fix other problems until you figure out how to do flow control _without_ causing undefined behavior.

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < regPassword.length(); k++)` also when they set true inside the loop they just keep looking for more truthfulness yet again and not breaking out.

Comment: How would i be able to change the 'main' bit? Main is where the main menu is displayed hence why ive called it but it does make sense thinking about it now why its not allowed

Comment: *How would i be able to change the 'main' bit?* -- Create a function `mainmenu();` and call that instead.  Now you are forced to move the stuff you have in `main` now into that function. -- *sorry if its a clusterbomb of code its abit all over the place* -- That is a big issue, not a small one.  For example, the check for a good password should be a separate function.

Comment: You also have a hint to how in your own code: _"returning to main menu"_. Then use `return` to return.

Comment: `8 || regPassword` did you really mean a logical OR here?

Comment: `if (regPassword.length() >= 8 || regPassword.length() <= 20)`: every number is greater-than-or-equal-to 8 **or** less-than-or-equal-to 20. The condition should test for numbers that satisfy **both** requirements, not one or the other.

Comment: Yeah so it was originally && i just changed it to || figuring i was being stupid. Still not really getting the password stuff though for some reason, i guess this is why so many people quit c++ haha.

Comment: I originally attempted to write the function seperately but it wasnt running for some reason, this is my first project trying to work without a tutorial so im just learning as i go really

Comment: I say your biggest obstacle to fixing your code is you don't know how to use your debugger effectively. What that means is you need to be able to get your debugger to step exactly 1 line and then you look at your variables and flow and then repeat until you see something happen that you did not expect.

Comment: *i guess this is why so many people quit c++* -- You probably would have encountered the same or similar issues, no matter what computer language you used.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented for you a simple class that deals with password complexity in c++. Please take a look.

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

class PasswordConstraint {
private:
    int minLength = 8;  // Default value for minLength
    int maxLength = 20; // Default value for maxLength
    bool requireLowercase = false; // Default value for requireLowercase
    bool requireUppercase = false; // Default value for requireUppercase
    bool requireNumbers = false;   // Default value for requireNumbers
    bool requireSpecialChars = false; // Default value for requireSpecialChars

public:
    int getMinLength() const {
        return minLength;
    }

    void setMinLength(int length) {
        minLength = length;
    }

    int getMaxLength() const {
        return maxLength;
    }

    void setMaxLength(int length) {
        maxLength = length;
    }

    bool isRequireLowercase() const {
        return requireLowercase;
    }

    void setRequireLowercase(bool value) {
        requireLowercase = value;
    }

    bool isRequireUppercase() const {
        return requireUppercase;
    }

    void setRequireUppercase(bool value) {
        requireUppercase = value;
    }

    bool isRequireNumbers() const {
        return requireNumbers;
    }

    void setRequireNumbers(bool value) {
        requireNumbers = value;
    }

    bool isRequireSpecialChars() const {
        return requireSpecialChars;
    }

    void setRequireSpecialChars(bool value) {
        requireSpecialChars = value;
    }

    bool isLengthValid(const std::string& value) const {
        return value.length() >= minLength && value.length() <= maxLength;
    }

    bool hasLowercase(const std::string& value) const {
        return std::regex_search(value, std::regex("[a-z]"));
    }

    bool hasUppercase(const std::string& value) const {
        return std::regex_search(value, std::regex("[A-Z]"));
    }

    bool hasNumbers(const std::string& value) const {
        return std::regex_search(value, std::regex("[0-9]"));
    }

    bool hasSpecialChars(const std::string& value) const {
        return std::regex_search(value, std::regex("[!@#%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>]"));
    }
};

void validatePassword(const std::string& value, const PasswordConstraint& constraint) {
    if (!constraint.isLengthValid(value)) {
        std::cout << "Error: Password should have a minimum length of " << constraint.getMinLength()
                  << " and a maximum length of " << constraint.getMaxLength() << std::endl;
    }

    if (constraint.isRequireLowercase() && !constraint.hasLowercase(value)) {
        std::cout << "Error: Password should contain at least one lowercase letter" << std::endl;
    }

    if (constraint.isRequireUppercase() && !constraint.hasUppercase(value)) {
        std::cout << "Error: Password should contain at least one uppercase letter" << std::endl;
    }

    if (constraint.isRequireNumbers() && !constraint.hasNumbers(value)) {
        std::cout << "Error: Password should contain at least one number" << std::endl;
    }

    if (constraint.isRequireSpecialChars() && !constraint.hasSpecialChars(value)) {
        std::cout << "Error: Password should contain at least one special character" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Enter a password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    PasswordConstraint constraint;
    constraint.setMinLength(8);
    constraint.setMaxLength(20);
    constraint.setRequireLowercase(true);
    constraint.setRequireUppercase(true);
    constraint.setRequireNumbers(true);
    constraint.setRequireSpecialChars(true);

    validatePassword(password, constraint);

    return 0;
}
```

You can customize the format of validatePassword function. It can return boolean instead of a simple output to the console or try to throw exception and catch it somewhere later.

Comment: I was hesitating to upvote because of the use of the regex hammer for such trivial tasks but I'm in a good mood.